# Dual space $E'$ is metrizable iff $E$ has a countable basis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

I saw that it was already asked, but the book where I'm studying is slightly different. Recall some definition, if $E$ it's $\mathbb{K}$-vector space and let $\mathcal{E}$ be a vector subspace of the  algebraic dual of $E$, wich is the vector space of all linear forms on $E$. We say that $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is a dual couple if $\mathcal{E}$ separates points of $E$, that is, $u(x)=u(y)$ $\forall u \in \mathcal{E}$ implies $x=y$. We have the following result:

1. "Suppose $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is a dual couple , $u_1,...,u_n , u \in  \mathcal{E}$.
   Then $u=\sum_{k=1}^n \lambda_k u_k$ iff $u_1(x)=...=u_n(x)=0$ implies $u(x)=0$"

Exercise (a): Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional locally convex space. Prove that the weak* topology $\sigma(E',E)$ on $E'$ is metrizable if and only if $E$ has a countable algebraic basis.

Hint (a): Let $U_n=\lbrace \max\lbrace p_{x_1},...,p_{x_N} \rbrace < 1/M \rbrace$. If $x \in E$, every ball $\lbrace p_x < \epsilon \rbrace$ contains some $U_n$; that is, $|u(x_j| < 1/n$ $\forall j$ implies $|u(x)| <1$. Hence $u(x_1)= \cdot \cdot \cdot u(x_N)=0$ implies $u(x)=0$ and $x \in \mathrm{span}(x_1,...,x_n)$.

Proof (Exercise (a)).
We assume that the weak* topology $\sigma(E',E)$ on $E'$ it's metrizable. Let $x_1,...,x_N \in E \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$. Note that the weak* topology is defined by seminorm family $\mathcal{F}= \lbrace p_x(u)=|u(x)| : x \in E \rbrace$, where 
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle U_n := \lbrace u \in E' : \max \lbrace p_{x_1}(u),...,p_{x_N}(u) \rbrace < 1/n \rbrace
\end{align*}
It is an open neighborhood in weak* topology.
By hypothesis $\forall x \in E$, $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ and exists open ball $B_{E'}:=\lbrace u \in E' : p_x(u):=|u(x)| < \epsilon \rbrace$ such that $U_n \subset B_{E'}$.
Now, if $u \in  U_n$ we have $|u(x_j)| < 1/n$ $\forall j$ and then $|u(x)|< 1$ with $\epsilon=1$, and by (1) we have:
\begin{align*}
u(x_1)=...=u(x_N)=0 \Longrightarrow 0=u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j u(x_j)
\end{align*}
by  linearity $x \in \mathrm{span}(x_1,...,x_n)$.
Reciprocally, just reverse the above implications, using results in (1)?

Someone can help me? can you check if proof of exercise (a) is correct?
Thank you.

Comment: There are few things I do not understand: Why do you get $|u(x)|<1$ and not $|u(x)| \leq \max_{1\leq j\leq N} |\lambda_j$? I also do not see why the hypothesis implies $U_n \subset B_{E'}$. I also do not really understand the formulation of the hint, where in the definition of $U_n$, $n$ does not appear on the right-hand-side.

Comment: Hi @Christian thanks for the reply, the exercise suggestion says exactly so as. I have tried to carry out the exercise based on this, but I find it difficult to understand. However, the book is "Linear Functional Analysis" by J. Cerdà.

Comment: Perhaps the hypothesis that $U_n \subset B_{E'}$ it's true since weak* topology is waekest topology on $E'$ that make continuous each linear functional?

Comment: Okay, so $x_1,\ldots, x_N$ are not chosen in advance but using that the family $\{\{\max\{p_{x_1},\ldots, p_{x_N}\}<1/M \colon x_1,\ldots, x_N\in E, M\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a fundamental system of neighbourhoods of zero of the weak$^*$ topology?

Comment: @Christian yes it's correct

Comment: At the moment I don't see where you are using metrizability

Comment: @Christian the hypothesis of metrizability it should say that every neighborhood "strong" is also weak* neightbhoood and mutually, so the open ball with respect to strong topology (induced by norm on $E'$) it takes the form $B_{E'}=\lbrace u \in E' : p_x(u):=|u(x)| < \epsilon \rbrace$. At least I think so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44539/discussion-between-christian-and-john-martin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filling in some details into your argument above yields the following:

Assume that the weak$^*$-topology on $E'$ is metrizable, then there is a countable basis $\{V_n\}$ of neighbournoods of zero. Each of these contains a set of the form
$$U_n:=\{u\in E'\colon \max\{p_{x_{n,1}}, \ldots, p_{x_{n,\varepsilon_n}}\} < 1/M_n\},$$
where $N_n,M_n\in\mathbb{N}$, since the latter is a basis of neighbourhoods of zero for the weak$^*$-topology.
So for every $x\in E$ and every $\varepsilon>0$, the set
$$
\{u\in E'\colon |u(x)|<\varepsilon\}
$$
contains a set $U_n$. Hence $u(x_{n,1})=\ldots u(x_{n,N_n})=0$ implies $u(x)=0$ and therefore $x\in\operatorname{span}\{x_{n,1},\ldots,x_{n,N_n}\}$. Therefore 
$$
\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{x_{n,1},\ldots,x_{n,N_n}\}
$$
is a countable basis of $E$.

To prove the other implication, let $\{x_n\}$ be a countable basis of $E$ and set
$$
U_{m,n} := \left\{u\in E'\colon \max_{1\leq i\leq n} |u(x_i)| < \frac{1}{m}\right\}.
$$
We have to show that $\{U_{m,n}\colon m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is a basis of neighbourhoods of zero. Let $x\in E$, then there is an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda_i x_i$ for some $\lambda_i$. We get
$$
|u(x)| \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N} |\lambda_i| |u(x_i)| \leq C \max_{1\leq i \leq N} |u(x_i)|,
$$
where $C:=\sum_{i=1}^{N} |\lambda_i|$. Hence every set of the form
$$
\{u\in E'\colon |u(x)| < \varepsilon\}
$$
and therefore also finite intersections of these, contains a set of the form $U_{n,m}$.

Comment: Where did you use the local convexity of $E$?

Comment: @DamianSobota: I think I did not. The topology on $E$ is only used for the definition of $E'$ but this should work for every dual pair $(E,F)$.

Comment: Exactly. And that's what makes me confused. If we consider $E=L_p([0,1])$ for $0<p<1$, then $E'=\{0\}$, so $E'$ is weakly* metrizable, but the dimension of $E$ is uncountable.

Comment: @DamianSobota Ok, I think that now I see what's going on: We need that the dual pair separates points, this is not the case in your example but guaranteed for locally convex spaces.

Comment: Where exactly do we need this assumption?

Comment: @DamianSobota: we know that $u(x_{n,1})=\ldots=u(x_{n,N_n})=0\Rightarrow u(x)=0$ or phrased differently that $\ker \langle x, \cdot\rangle \subset \bigcap \ker \langle x_{n,k}, \cdot\rangle$. This implies that as (continuous) linear forms on $E'$ we have that $x$ is in the span of the others. Now if the dual pairing separates points, we know that these linear forms are exactly $E$, so $x$ has to be in the span of the other points (as elements of $E$). I think this is one of the places where the argument breaks down in the non-locally convex case.

Comment: The inclusion of the kernels is in the other direction ;) But I don't see why the separation of points implies that those vectors $x_{n,m}$'s span the whole space $E$. In my opinion it just follows from the fact that inclusion of the kernels implies that the functional is a linear combination of the others, which does not require any topology.

Comment: @DamianSobota: We know that the linear functional $\langle x,\cdot\rangle$ is in the span of $\langle x_{n,1},\cdot\rangle, \ldots,\langle x_{n,N_n},\cdot\rangle$ (for $E=L_p[0,1]$ this also true since all of them are the zero functional), i.e. $\langle x, \cdot\rangle=\sum\lambda_i \langle x_{n,i}, \cdot\rangle$ and $\langle x-\sum\lambda_ix_{n,i},u\rangle=0$ for all $u\in E'$. If $(E,E')$ separates points, we may conclude that $x=\sum\lambda_ix_{n,i}$.

Comment: I see! So we just need that $E'$ separates points to conclude that $x=\sum\lambda_i x_{n,i}$ from the equality of the appropriate functionals. Great! Thank you :)

Comment: Sorry for asking this late, but why can we conclude: "$u(x_{n,1})=\ldots u(x_{n,N_n})=0$ implies $u(x)=0$"? Thanks.

Comment: If $V_{x,\epsilon}:=\{u\in E'\colon |u(x)|<\varepsilon\}$ contains $U_{n, M_n}:=\{u\in E'\colon \max\{p_{x_{n,1}}, \ldots, p_{x_{n,N_n}}\} < 1/M_n\}$, then we also have, for every $\eta>0$, $U_{n, \frac{M_n}{\eta}}\subset V_{x, \eta\epsilon}$. As $\eta$ changes, the points $x_{n,1}, \cdots, x_{n, N_n}$ are fixed. So if $u(x_{n,j})=0$ for all $1\leq j \leq N_n$, then $u\in U_{n, \frac{M_n}{\eta}}\subset V_{x, \eta\epsilon}$, for all $\eta>0$. Then, we have $u\in \cap_{\eta>0} V_{x, \eta\epsilon}$. That is $u(x)=0$. Correct?